# maximum number of dominoes can be placed inside a figure

Tags: algorithm, max

Suppose some figure on the squared paper. Sides of the figure go straight on the lines of squared paper. Figure may have any (not even convex) shape. How to find the maximum number of dominoes (1x2 rectangular) that can be placed in that figure. It is not allowed to put domino over another one. It is allowed to put domino only in such way, when its sides fall exactly on the lines of squared paper.

Comment: what have you tried to find out yourself? what exactly is your problem here? can you give some examples? is this homework?

Comment: it is not a homework, I got this problem from my friend, tried to solve it with pencil and paper and could not. Now I don't know any solution except brute force. I tried several euristics, but there is always an example when my solution is not best.

Comment: @Sega: you need to state the question more precisely or it will probably be closed. How is the boundary defined, for example ?

Comment: I rewrited the question and added some statements about the shape.

Comment: what does it mean I represent my question?

Comment: How connected is the figure?  Is there a path between any two squares (without using diagonals)?

Comment: Svante, I think it is not important, cause it is simple to get all such connected figures, and to solve problem for each separately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the [maximum cardinality matching problem in a bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs). The squares are the vertices and the dominoes are the edges that belong to the matching.

To see that the graph is bipartite, imagine the squares are checkerboard-painted. Black ones only neighbour white ones and vice versa.

Comment: Can this solution be generalized?  What if the domiNos are 3x1 or 4x2, for example?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Yes, of course it can be generalized! It's "just" a matching in a hypergraph :)

Answer (score 0):

You can classify squares by the number of neighbor free squares as type 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

I believe that should work:

1. find a type 1 square, place there a domino in the only possible way and repeat
2. else, find a free corner formed by two contiguous type 2 and type 3 squares, place there a domino and go to 1
3. else, place a domino in any type 2 square and go to 1
4. you are done

Comment: Yes, this is basically what the simplest maximum matching algorithm does.